# How to pass input type file (i.e. image) directory as session

Tags: php, mysql

I have a multi-step form in which i have to choose an image in step 3 and have to pass the image directory or path as a session in another input field in step 4 before submitting form.How I can pass the image path to finally keep it in database??Please Help !( PHP & Mysql)

Comment: Why don't you just ask the file in step 4?

Comment: @Esailija
I have to show user a page containing his filled input fields.This is why she/he can get a chance to edit or modify his entered info.and this page contains only the input field filled up with the info of previous steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  There is no way to know where on the user's hard drive a file is stored, let alone a way to go and get it from the web browser (imagine if I made a website that went after your windows directory files; even your password files -- there are obvious security reasons why web browsers don't allow this).

What you *can* do is upload the image, then use info stored in `$_FILES` to temporarily track where the file is located on the server, and at final submission do whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions.I am novice at this site,so if i would have mistake,then purdon me,,
I have uploaded the image file in a temporary folder of server.but for finally storing in database,how to retrieve the image without requiring further input form user?? what's the correspoding php/mysql code?? please give a solution

Comment: read the file from the temp location into the database.... I'm not here to do your work for you.  Do the research, and if you have a specific question, let us know what you've tried and what did/didn't work, and then we can help.  This isn't a "free code" site.